# How To Change Opencart Product Tag Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, opencart

I want to change product tags url from `mysite.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_tag=keyword` to `mysite.com/xyz/keyword`.

I successfully changed `index.php?route=product/search&filter_tag=` to a folder name like `xyz` through .htaccess. I can use it only if I write it manually to address bar.

But I can't change the href code through catalog/controller/product/product.php.

The code is `'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', 'filter_tag=' . trim($tag))`. How can I edit this to be like `mysite.com/xyz/keyword`?

Comment: any updates? I am also interested in it

Answer (score 0):

- If you just want to change the product search page, then go to `Class URL @ Method link` located in **system/library/url.php** and add some code that checks if the parameter is `'product/search'` then return the desired format, whenever the page is requested, the **.htaccess** modifications that you have made will handle the rest
- If you are trying to change the way in which open cart controls routing (all pages),then you have to hack some code in three classes:
  (1) `class Action` located in **system/engine/action.php** which is responsible for parsing the `route` parameter
  (2) `class Front` located in **system/engine/front.php** which is responsible for instantiating controllers and calling methods based on the `route` parameter parsed by `class Action`
  (3) `class URL` located in **system/library/url.php** which is responsible for generating pages urls
  **Note** these classes may differ slightly in different versions

Comment: I couldn't make it. I don't want to change any search function or any other pages. I just want to edit tags(url) in the product page.

Comment: who said any thing about changing search functions?

Comment: No I did not say it for you. It is for future comments. I just want to edit this line 'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', 'filter_tag=' . trim($tag))